# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') in my messenger webhook event

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

can some one explain me this..

in My messenger bot I have following code:

```
entry.messaging.forEach(async function (webhookEvent) {
    // Discard uninteresting events
    if ("read" in webhookEvent) {
      console.log("Got a read event");
      return;
    } else if ("delivery" in webhookEvent) {
      console.log("Got a delivery event");
      return;
    } else if (webhookEvent.message && webhookEvent.message.is_echo) {
      console.log(
        "Got an echo of our send, mid = " + webhookEvent.message.mid
      );
      return;
    }
```

The error I get:

```
entry.messaging.forEach( /*#__PURE__*/function () {
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

Comment: `messaging` is `undefined`

Comment: `entry.messaging` is undefined ... should it be something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the existing of entry.messaging at first then create a forEach loop for it. Like below:

```
entry.messaging && entry.messaging.forEach(...)
```